# Typescript not building in Container-based Azure Function App

Tags: typescript, azure, docker, azure-function-app

I am deploying to an Azure Function App from a container inside Azure Container Registry.

I initially used the `func init` command (chose typescript option), and added some code using the service bus topic trigger template. When I run `npm start` locally, i can get it to work. There is a "prestart" command that builds the typescript, inside the package.json, it looks like

```
"prestart": "npm run build && func extensions install",
```

The build creates a dist directory so when it starts, I can see this:

```
[8/14/19 8:45:43 PM] 1 functions loaded
```

All is good. The problems start when I deploy this function to my function app. I am deploying from the Azure Container Registry.

Via Kudu, I can see the container error logs:

```
2019-08-14T20:51:05.870505061Z       The following 1 functions are in error:
2019-08-14T20:51:05.870515162Z       ehmTopicTrigger: Invalid script file name configuration. The 'scriptFile' property is set to a file that does not exist.
2019-08-14T20:51:05.870540263Z
```

When I run `func start` locally and my dist directory doesn't exist, I get the exact same error. This leads me to believe that when the docker container starts in the Function App, it is not running `npm start` (or for whatever reason, its not building and creating `dist`).

I don't think committing and deploying the `dist` directory is the answer, because the .gitignore provided by the template includes /dist.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added npm run build to the docker file and its working now.

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:2.0

 ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

 COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

 RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install && \
    npm run build
```

This builds the dist folder within the container.

Comment: this code snippet is help full for build and run container for node based azureFunc app